# Why can't Elasticsearch bulk API parse my JSON?

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have this JSON-like data that I am `PUT`ing via a HTTP request to an Elasticsearch API /_bulk endpoint:

```
{"update":{"_id":1,"_type":"myType","_index":"myIndex"}}
{"doc":{"id":1,"name":"Foo"},"doc_as_upsert":true}
{"update":{"_id":2,"_type":"myType","_index":"myIndex"}}
{"doc":{"id":2,"name":"Bar"},"doc_as_upsert":true}
```

When I `PUT` the data via Postman (a Google Chrome app) it works successfully.

When I `PUT` the data via my Node.js script (a `request()` call), I get this error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "parse_exception",
      "reason" : "Failed to derive xcontent"
    } ],
    "type" : "parse_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to derive xcontent"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I'm sending (what I assume is) the exact same data both ways but only Postman is working. I am ending each line with a \n character (including the last one) and I believe my formatting is correct.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Edit: the Node code (simplified):

```
var sourceData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('test-data.json', 'utf8')),

sourceData.forEach(function(data) {
    var docid = data.id;

    updates.push(JSON.stringify({
        update: {
            _id: docid,
            _type: config.elasticsearch.type,
            _index: config.elasticsearch.index
        }
    }));

    updates.push(JSON.stringify({
        doc: data,
        doc_as_upsert: true
    }));
});

updates = updates.join("\n") + "\n";

request({
    uri: 'http://my-endpoint/_bulk',
    method: 'POST',
    data: updates,
    proxy: 'http://' + config.proxy.host + ':' + config.proxy.port
}, function() { ... });
```

Comment: Can you show your node.js code?

Comment: Are you sure that the `Content-Type` header is set to text/plain and not application/json?

Comment: And if I'm not mistaken, you need to use the `body` parameter to send the updates, not `data` (which is for multipart requests)

Comment: @Val ......... I was using `data` not `body`. Goddamnit. Thanks. If you make a new answer I'll tick that.

Comment: Glad we figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `body` parameter to send the updates, not `data` (which is for multipart requests)

```
request({
    uri: 'http://my-endpoint/_bulk',
    method: 'POST',
    body: updates,               // <---- change this
    proxy: 'http://' + config.proxy.host + ':' + config.proxy.port
}, function() { ... });
```